# Linux: Howto get same output filenames of batch conversion with different extension?

Tags: linux, batch-rename

I am using Timidity to convert a lot of midi files to mp3. 
I was wondering if there is a standard way of specifying a output pattern so that it converts all the `*.mid` files to `/path/*.wav`

I ask this in general because it would also be the case in a `mv` command. Or is this tied to a specific implementation in the app?

So, how to move a *.mid files to *.wav ?

Comment: In the case of `mv` command, have you seen [mmv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mmv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you just wanted to rename files. Then if you are using a Bourne shell (such as `sh`, `bash`) you can run the command on files matching a pattern using a `for` loop. Here are equivalent multiline and single-line versions:

```
for f in *.mid
do
    mv "$f" "${f%.mid}.wav"
done
```

```
for f in *.mid; do mv "$f" "${f%.mid}.wav"; done
```

The `for` loop runs the commands with `$f` being each word in the expansion of `*.mid`, and `${f%.mid}` removes the suffix `.mid` so that we can replace it with `.wav`. The quotes make this program correct for filenames containing spaces (but not filenames starting with "-", as that depends on the command). If you want to match several groups of files rather than everything, you can use multiple patterns like `for f in alpha-*.mid beta-*.mid; do ...`

You can use any command you want in place of `mv`. I took a look at Timidity's man page, but I couldn't figure out where it takes an output filename so I haven't given an example.

Answer (score 1):

I made a python script that moves *.mid to *.wav.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import sys
import glob
import shutil
import os

try:
    dir = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Usage: "+sys.argv[0]+" dir"
    print "Example: "+sys.argv[0]+" /home/user/dir"
    sys.exit(1)

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.mid')):
    newfile = file.partition(".mid")
    newfile = newfile[0]
    newfile = newfile+".wav"
    shutil.move(file, newfile)
```

Comment: This doesn't generalize to performing operations other than renaming as Peterdk wants.